# linkify on textview with domain in text not working, links not clickable

Tags: android, linkify

I'm not able to `linkfy` a string with a `href` when the string says the domain name with it.  so string. let me show you.

Here is the string:

```
<string name="go_to_settings">Please go to "Settings" in <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/settings">mywebsite.com</a> to change this status</string>
```

**And it would say this to the user: "Please go to "Settings" in mywebsite.com to change this status. "**

here is the `textview` I'm using:

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_instructions"
      android:layout_width="280dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
      android:textColorLink="@color/action_blue"
      android:linksClickable="true"
      android:text="@string/go_to_settings"/>
```

and here is how i am trying to make the link `clickable`:

```
 Linkify.addLinks(tv_instructions, Linkify.ALL)
 tv_instructions.movementMethod=LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

But i am seeing happen on api 24 and 27 device and emulator is that the link is going to www.mywebsite.com instead of www.mywebsite/settings

but here is the strange thing, if i change the text the user sees and remove .com from that then it works fine.  so if the user see this instead it works:

**and it would say this to the user: "Please go to "Settings" in mywebsite to change this status. "**

notice there is no .com being mentioned.  How can i get this displayed.  i also tried this way:

```
tv_instructions.text=(utils.fromHTML(resources.getString(R.string.go_to_settings),null))
tv_instructions.movementMethod=LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

and textview like this:

```
    <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tv_instructions"
                       android:layout_width="280dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
                       android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
                       android:textAlignment="center"
                       android:textColor="#5c5c5c"

                       android:text="@string/go_to_settings"
               />
```

you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: test case `android:autoLink="web"`

Comment: i removed the call in linkify all, in code and did as you said in xml. same results

Comment: did you open to links in browser

Comment: the links open fine in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.  for some reason i needed to wrap my text as character data using tag `cData` in my `strings` file.  this works:

```
<string name="go_to_settings"><![CDATA[Please go to "Settings" in <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/settings">mywebsite.com</a> to change this status :]]></string>
```

then the `textview` looks like this:

```
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_instructions"
      android:layout_width="280dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
      android:text="@string/go_to_settings"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
      android:textColorLink="@color/action_blue"/>
```

Java Code

```
tv_instructions.text=(utils.fromHTML(resources.getString(R.string.go_to_settings),null))
tv_instructions.movementMethod=LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Comment: the only thing that worked for me. is this. adding CDATA !!

Answer (score 1):

> linkify on textview with domain in text not working, links not clickable

You can also use [**`ClickableSpan`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan)

> If an object of this type is attached to the text of a `TextView` with a movement method of `LinkMovementMethod`, the affected spans of text can be selected. If selected and clicked, the `onClick(View)` method will be called.

**Check below SAMPLE CODE**

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextview);

        setSpan();
    }

    private void setSpan() {

        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder("Please go to \"Settings\" in");
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" mywebsite.com ");

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // you can open your link here as per your requiremnt
            }
        };

        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannableString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);

        spannableStringBuilder.append(spannableString);
        spannableStringBuilder.append("to change this status");

        myTextView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
        myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }


}
```

Comment: this is also a good way to do it but i didn't want to write the code, +1